# How do I search for questions and answers I have upvoted?

Tags: support, search, up-votes

I know I can see a list of upvotes in the user profile section, but the list is paginated so I often have to click through the pages to find a specific answer.

It would be very helpful if it was possible to search/filter the upvotes list.  Is there a way to do this I have not yet found?

Comment: I saw that but the accepted answer was to see the list of upvotes where as I want to be able to search upvotes.

Comment: A related feature request: [Search by keyword for answer / question I upvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224344).

Comment: post noted by Martin is actually one for redirecting from this dup not one marked now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't search for posts you upvoted. The only thing you can do is browse the list of your upvoted posts.

You can find that list in your profile: votes --> upvotes.

Comment: I now comment on everything. Is this the case still that we can't find things we've upvoted? I certainly can't.

Answer (score -10):

Why would you want to find a specific post you upvoted at all?

The system keeps track of the posts you upvoted, in my opinion, just to prevent the opportunity to upvote them more than once. With all other situations we're bound to the anonymity of voting process principle that should be enforced at all times. Moreover, we're not able to change the vote after a certain period of time has passed (5 minutes), unless some action has been undertaken on the post text.

So, the upvotes section is there just for you personal memories and should be left as it is. A more comprehensive control on the upvoted posts could lead to some negative consequences, like a possible increase in the number of 'revenge' votes.

Finally, you upvoted a post because you found a question/answer to be helpful, full stop, move over.

Comment: If I find a question/answer to be helpful, then it is perfectly reasonable to assume I may want to refer to it again in the future, is it not?

Comment: That's why there are favourites out there. I personally don't know how it could be of help to me, but that's my opinion.

Comment: The favorites feature used to be quite spammy because it would alert me whenever something had changed on the page. It discouraged me from using it. Has that changed now?

Comment: I can't disagree with this answer any more.

Comment: So, I'm looking for an answer to a problem; I read 30 answers, nothing in there, I "move over"; then I read something that *might* have an answer, but doesn't look like it, because I still lack some information - here's an upvote (maybe I'd add it to favorites, if it had a full solution, but I don't see it atm, so why pollute my favorites?); after like couple of hours or so, I've went through 200 posts and given 20 upvotes; then I realize 10 days later, with more knowledge, that the first one *may* have been the answer - but how do I find it?